# Docker on Linux (Manjaro), after system update change location of socket from /var/run/docker.sock to /run/docker.soc - docker doesn't work

Tags: docker, manjaro, socket

After I made regular update of system and apllication, docker (and docker-compose plugin) doesn't work:

```
permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock
```

If I use sudo ls -la /var/run/docker.sock:

```
/var/run/docker.sock: No such file or directory (os error 2).
```

And if I use: sudo systemctl status docker, I see other location of socket:

```
level=info msg="API listen on /run/docker.sock"
```

At the moment I am using only link solution:

```
sudo ln -s /run/docker.sock /var/run/docker.sock
```

Where is make socket adress? And can I change somewhere config for this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into this as well as part of this update. Somehow `/var/run`, which is supposed to always be symlinked to `/run` got turned into an actual directory, and so the docker socket was not in the correct location.

I was able to resolve by doing the following:

1. Stop/Disable/Remove Docker

   - `sudo systemctl stop docker`
   - `sudo systemctl disable docker`
   - `sudo pacman -Rs docker`
2. Reboot
3. `sudo rm -rf /var/run`
4. Reboot.
5. `/var/run` is now a symlink again

   ```
   ls -al /var/run 
   lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 6 Sep 19 14:04 /var/run -> ../run
   ```
6. Reinstall/start/enable Docker.

   - `sudo pacman -S docker`
   - `sudo systemctl start docker`
   - `sudo systemctl enable docker`
7. `docker.sock` is now in `/run` and docker commands for the
   docker group run correctly again.

   ```
   ls -al /var/run/docker.sock
   srw-rw---- 1 root docker 0 Sep 19 14:06 /var/run/docker.sock
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Simply:

```
ln -sv /run /var/run
```

Nothing more, nothing less.